# Socket.io connection joining the wrong room

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

When a request is made to `localhost:3000/:id` I want to create a room and add the client to it. Then I want the actions taken by that client to only be broadcasted to the other clients in that room. here's the server side code that handles that:

```
app.get('/:id', function response(req, res) {
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {

            socket.join('/game-' + req.params.id);

            socket.on('action', function (action) {
                switch (action.type) {
                    case 'TOGGLE_ACTIVE_PLAYER':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', toggleActivePlayer())
                    case 'SET_SLOT_PREVIEW':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', setSlotPreview(action.colIndex))
                    case 'CLEAR_SLOT_PREVIEW':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', clearSlotPreview(action.colIndex))
                    case 'PLAYER_MOVED':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', playerMoved(action.colIndex))
                    case 'CHECK_FOR_WINNER':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', checkForWinner())
                    case 'CLEAR_BOARD':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', clearBoard())
                    case 'CLEAR_WINNER':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', clearWinner())
                    case 'RESET_GAME':
                        return socket.broadcast.to('/game-' + req.params.id).emit('action', resetGame())
                }
            })
    });
    res.end();
});
```

The problem I'm having is that when a connection is made with a new id param (localhost:300/newIdParam) a room called newIdParam gets created and that client gets added to it BUT that client also gets inappropriately added to an existing room. I can tell the client is in both rooms by inspecting the `io.sockets.adapter.rooms` object:

```
  '/game-123': 
   Room {
     sockets: 
      { '/#KIq0i-_oaf_mtM8AAAAK': true,
        '/#Sokr_2ROg0culZ6bAAAL': true,
        '/#w6XRgbfF3Q2TIicXAAAM': true },
     length: 3 },
  '/#Sokr_2ROg0culZ6bAAAL': Room { sockets: { '/#Sokr_2ROg0culZ6bAAAL': true }, length: 1 },
  '/#w6XRgbfF3Q2TIicXAAAM': Room { sockets: { '/#w6XRgbfF3Q2TIicXAAAM': true }, length: 1 },
  '/game-456': Room { sockets: { '/#w6XRgbfF3Q2TIicXAAAM': true }, length: 1 } }
```

Notice socket id `#w6XRgbfF3Q2TIicXAAAM` exists in both rooms. Again these rooms are created simply by making a request to with the id as a route parameter like this:

`localhost:3000/123`

That request would create a room called game-123 and the requesting client automatically gets added.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: As a side comment, how come you don't just emit the `action.type` as the event name? That would break up your logic a little bit and you wouldn't need a switch-case block.

Comment: The client side app is emitting redux actions to the server so this is kinda just a server side reducer and it's pretty common for redux reducers to user switch statements. that's the only reason i decided to go with a switch statement.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I've always found the way redux is written to be sort of a JavaScript antipattern, personally, but I suppose that's getting more into opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Here if you need something like if user connects to new room then user should not be in old one so there will be only one room with which user is connected then you have to force user to leave room on disconnect as shown below,

```
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    socket.leave("roomname");
});
```